# Connect a Laptop with a 5.1 Sound System

Tags: laptop, sound-card

I will be replacing my desktop computer with a laptop and I would like to connect it to my existing 5.1 sound system.  Now, the Sound System have three different input channels, but most laptops only have one sound output channel. what do I need in order to connect my future laptop to my sound system? Do I need a sound card?

Example Laptop: ASUS N53JF-XE1
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00492C6TI/ref=ord_cart_shr?ie=UTF8&m=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00492C6TI)

Comment: I would not pay almost $1000 for that laptop, although it's not a particularly bad laptop.

Comment: Any recommandtion for that price??? xD I am open to any advice!

Comment: This quesiton has been edited to focus on the sound card connection question of a laptop.  Shopping questions are off-topic on SU, so I modified your question to be more suitable.  For more info, please see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the laptop's headphone port has an s/pdif output mode, probably enabled in the sound settings in windows. Depending on what kind of receiver you have, you might have a compatible input for this. Barring this, USB sound cards are a possibility. I have a 2 channel one that works well.

Comment: mmm I just check. My Receiver does not have a compatible input. It has six input (3 pairs of inputs, red and white colors) So i have like 3 cables, one side 1 connector and the other side two connectors. One for each chanel.  Am I being clear here?

Answer (score 0):

The only laptops I have seen with built in 5.1 are gaming laptops.  They aren't super cheap (I think Alienware laptops might all have it).

Otherwise Spezz42's suggestion of a USB sound card is your best bet.

Comment: But most USB card I've seen on Amazon only have one output, for my receiver I need three (Black, Green and Blue color), So I have left, right, rear, front and subwoofer.

Comment: @m, Just googled "usb audio 5.1"  first result was an adapter listed on Amazon.

Comment: Thanks man. But that get me confused. they only have one output, I need 3 :S

Comment: @m, the image I see has 3 outputs.  There are a bunch: http://www.amazon.com/Zalman-ZM-RSSC-External-Sound-Card/dp/B0001OZ2K8  or http://www.amazon.com/PPA-1455-Sound-card-kHz/dp/tech-data/B001LLX6QW